# angular 2 - Problema ao chamar diretiva

Tags: angularjs, angular2-directives

Boa tarde galera....

## angular

Gostaria de ajuda de voces se possível.

Estou com problema ao utilizar uma diretiva.
Criamos uma diretiva em um diretorio diretiva, (app> directive) porém dentro do meu formulário não estou conseguindo utilizar. Temos 2 diretorios (empresa e filial) somente empresa consegue utilizar o recurso dessa diretiva. Não dá erro no module empresa.module e nem filial.module, mas ele cospe um erro no console e não carrega a página.

Esse é o erro:
compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Type IstMaskDirective is part of the declarations of 2 modules: EmpresaModule and FilialModule! Please consider moving IstMaskDirective to a higher module that imports EmpresaModule and FilialModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes IstMaskDirective then import that NgModule in EmpresaModule and FilialModule.

Comment: A diretiva para de funcionar quando temos alguns diretorios mais para dentro. Ex:  Ficou nesses Diretiva: diretorios app> directive> minhaDiretivaCnpj. Arquivo que chama a diretiva ficou em: app> filial> filial-form. Mas o engraçado é que quando eu uso a diretiva no diretorio:  app> filial ela funciona e consigo usar em filial e empresa, por exemplo

Comment: Acesse esse link que o mesmo deve resolver o seu problema :) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598311/component-is-part-of-the-declaration-of-2-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598311/component-is-part-of-the-declaration-of-2-modules)

Answer (score 0):

Muito provavelmente teu problema já foi resolvido, mas vou deixar a resposta para outros que passem pelo mesmo problema.

Uma diretiva só pode ser declarada em um módulo. Esta mensagem de erro significa que você declarou-a em dois módulos. O mesmo vale para componentes.
Uma sugestão de solução seria: declare sua diretiva em um módulo específico, e exporte-a no mesmo. Nos componentes onde você quiser utilizá-la, abra o módulo onde eles estão declarados e importe o módulo onde a diretiva foi exportada.